# Three state button for a medical chart

Tags: gui-design, buttons

I am working on UI design for a new web based medical charting system.  The users are used to charting on paper where they circle a symptom if it is present, cross it out if it is absent, and don't touch it at all if they don't address it.  I need to replicate those three states in the UI.  I don't want to use radio buttons since there is no conventional way to "clear" radio buttons, and three radio buttons per item feels cluttered.  I put a few ideas below, but I'd appreciate any input.

[image]

**Update 2**

[Here](https://github.com/emguide/threeStateSelect) is a jquery plugin that implements this design.  Go easy on me, I'm new to web coding.

**Update**

So here is how I decided to solve this problem, based on the answers from smurf and tim.baker below, modified for a mouse vs touch environment.

[image]

To keep the target areas from being too small, I made the entire half of the label a target.  Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d_j_k/2p92q/) so you can play with it.  Let me know what you think, I'm planning on making it into a jquery plugin.

Comment: What do you mean by they dont address it? They dont know about it or dont want to tell about it?

Comment: @Mervin I would think he means if it isn't applicable, so an exagerated version they skip over the "ankle pain" question if they know it is chest related. It's medical so I would think nothing would be leading, just because it seams irrelevant if they don't ask the question they can't click absent.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @David! If I'm understanding your diagram right, an answer of "no" (which is probably the most common answer) would require 2 clicks in any of the three options you propose.  On the other hand, radio buttons (with or without the common affordance of the circle beside the text) would require only one click each.  In a form with a lot of questions, that would require a **ton** of extra clicking.  Don't compromise usability for the sake of minimalist aesthetics.

Comment: @Mervin, Tim has it right, there are many things that might be in the template that the physician doesn't feel the need to address in the actual interview.

Comment: @3nafish that's a great point, the only reason I was looking for something else was that I wanted to replicate the ability of paper to let the user skip over the answer, but I could do that by defaulting an N/A button

Comment: @DavidK. - I know I was late to the party in answering, but you might want to take a look at my [answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/50815/40110).  Not only does it provide the UX portion, it includes a live demo of the code needed to make it work.  Give it a look!

Comment: Love the interaction with it, very simple, and clear feedback as to the result of your click.  The only thing I would change is more graphic-design oriented, like removing the border, for example.  But the idea and interaction seem great.

Comment: @smurf thanks, I'm turning it into a plugin now, so you can do

Comment: You may want to group things into logical chucks. So one section for negative symptoms e.g. dizziness and another for factual statements e.g. pregnant

Comment: One thing that stands out in your JFiddle is that clicking it again just sets it to nothing, clicking the other side should change the option, clicking the same option should change it to deselected.

Comment: In the fiddle, clicking the middle (with the name of the symptom) seems to alternate with the most recently selected state. Suggest that it should always cycle all three.

Comment: @smurf’s accepted answer has the check mark at the right-hand side which seems the more natural option for LTR languages. Your imagined pen is on the right-hand end after reading an entry, from there you would strike through back to the beginning and be finished, but your circle of approval ends where it started. That’s just an untested assumption, though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Seamless has a nice implementation of this actually:

[image: seamless cuisines]

Here, the user can slide each option either way, or just leave it and continue scrolling if the condition was not discussed.

Adapted from the elegant and modern design of @tim.baker (I would just add in the "x"s and "check"s, to help with clarity and in case of a person who is colorblind).  This also allows for clicking of the buttons, instead of swiping, which may be better for a mouse interface.  Whether to center, left justify, or right justify the symbols probably depends on how you want to align the text.

[image: tim.baker design]

If, however, you *do want to encourage swiping* I think you would need to change the design a bit, to something like the following (excuse the poor quality):

[image: tim.baker swiping]

So that it looks like one long bar to swipe along, rather than individual buttons.  And, when the user does swipe, the section they swipe actually moves, instead of just having text appear where they swiped to.

Comment: This is actually really slick, though I suspect it works better on a mobile device where the sliding gesture is a little more natural. +1

Comment: Yeah, agreed on that part.  Maybe the "x" and "check" areas could be more like buttons, and you could click either side?  I can imagine sliding a lot of those back and forth with a mouse could get annoying.

Comment: Thanks! That it really slick.  Seems intuitive and very easy to quickly scan.  I think it could be adapted to non-touch environment.

Comment: @smurf Let me know what you think of the above implementation.

Comment: Looks good to me. I'd say clicking the x is the same as sliding to the left. I'd label the column headers, "Absent", "Present". (Thinking more, I'm not sure what swiping actually adds though - as a user I'd probably just tap the tick/cross, even on touchscreen.)

Comment: It is not clear for me, it just looks confusing - some weird table with some weirdly colored cells. I see this for the first time and I just don't know how it works until I read about it or try touching something.

Answer (score 20):

Why not replicate the way the users are used to deal with this on a form? That's what you're basicaly already doing in your second mockup.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f49h7u.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The way to change from the one into the other would be clicking on it, and cycling through the three states.

Comment: Clear, simple and contextual with what users are used to. Love it! You could even do the slash from top left to bottom right if you auto-detect the user is left handed.

Comment: This seems like the best, simplest answer. I'm not sure what the goal of "unaddressed" is, but if it means that this is a non-issue, it might help to grey the text. That's only useful though if you want them to be able to ignore it. On the other hand, if you want to call out that it wasn't addressed, maybe a color change or font weight change to set it off would be beneficial.

Comment: This is simple and intuitive to *read*, unfortunately it is not intuitive to *enter* the data, and it requires two interactions to get to one of the states.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to speak to the part of your question where you said:

> I don't want to use radio buttons since there is no conventional way to "clear" radio buttons, and three radio buttons per item feels cluttered.

First, grouped radio buttons should ***always*** have one of the values checked.  If by clear, you mean reset, that's simply a routine that sets the form elements back to their default values.

Second, there's a way to not make the radio buttons look cluttered.  Let me explain:

Since you are creating a new web-based application, you most likely will be using JavaScript at some point for client side scripting.  I use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), a JavaScript library.  jQuery has a sister site called [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) for anything that has to do with the user interface. Check out their [Demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) and their [Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!zThemeParams=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) where you can customize your UI controls to match your color scheme.

What I want to focus on is one of the UI controls, the [Button](http://jqueryui.com/button).    It's your standard run-of-the-mill button, but with some varying functionality.  They did something really cool which was to combine radio buttons into what they call a [Button Set](http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio).  This is where you can de-clutter (if that's a word) your multiple radio button choices.

This is a great approach that will solve your issue.  It's clean.  It's simple.  And ... it's supported by the community.  I created a ***[live jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/Jy9te/)*** where you can interact with the choices or you can just view the screen capture below:

[image: default radio buttonset]

**Color to State Breakdown:**

- Black  ( Default )
- Blue   ( Hover )
- Orange ( Checked )

---

## **UPDATE**

As ***@smurf*** pointed out in the comments, these button sets by default are rather large and could draw your eye away from the actual question labels.  That's a very simple fix with a little css, so I went ahead and created another ***[live jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/6MwgW/)*** with larger question labels combined with smaller button sets:

[image: smaller radio buttonset]

Comment: I think the interaction with this is nice, and I like that it is very clear what I am clicking. One important thing I think needs to be improved though: I find myself looking directly at the buttons, and not focusing on the question that is being asked.  The actual symptom seems secondary to the idea of whether it exists or not.  This image: http://imgur.com/qmhJ1NH shows how your eyes jump right to the bold buttons and skip the content above.  Often that's good, but not perfect for this application I think.

Comment: @smurf - Duly noted; my answer has been updated to acknowledge the size issue.  However, like I said in my post, they have a Theme Roller where you can customize the colors of the UI controls.  This is their Darkness UI theme, so that's why they are darker and bolder.  You can make them much much subtler if you wish to.

Comment: Your second fiddle is a broken link :(

Comment: @BenVoigt - Oh crap! I accidentally purged it when I was removing some unnecessary fiddles.  I'll have to redo it.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Ok ... it has been updated.

Answer (score 6):

I am making an a couple of assumptions here (based on what your questions says obviously):

- Although experienced your users are mixed capability
- They are pressed for time
- Like most users they don't like change
- The "default" state is "Not Addressed" which essentially means N/A

On those assumptions I would use something highly visual which minimises the users tasks by setting a default and gives reassurance. Note: although I would like to use a cross through line, [this just never really works digitally](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/31127/23268).

**Default state:**
[image: default state]

The user can then swipe right (or click) to confirm the symptom is present:

**Symptom Present:**
[image]

**Not Present (left swipe):**
[image]

**What a set of symptoms may look like:**
[image]

Comment: That text being not centered is annoying me more than it should. :P. Is there a specific reason why you made it gravitate towards the center?

Comment: I am not surprised, it would annoy me to seeing it without being in my reasoning... Although not likely relevant it is there in case it will be viewed on different sized screens!

Comment: @tim.baker, thanks! this seems like a flatter version of what smurf posted, I really like this solution.  The baseline is N/A, one click for either direction, this seems very intuative

Comment: @DavidK. Although I like smurfs I have to say I think this has the edge - as you are displaying all 3 possibilities (not requiring the need to scroll first) you are eliminating a lot of potential errors. Should be very intuitive :) [I almost think of it as a Tinder swipe perhaps?!]

Comment: This is great.  But if the user is swiping something, I think they usually want it to follow their swipe.  See the edit to my post for my further suggestions.

Comment: @tim.baker Let me know what you think of the above implementation.

Comment: @DavidK. I like it, the only thing is although you can reset it back to the default state, it isn't clear how which could cause you some issues?

Comment: I find the colors confusing,I associate having a symptom e.g. chest pain as bad and therefore red..

Comment: @AndyM My thoughts exactly.

Comment: @AndyM I agree. It is a bit of a double edge sword. Green for selected or red for its a bad thing... Difficult

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest something more "humanistic". Like a question they have to answer.

> Chest Pain : Yes | No | I don't know

By default there is nothing selected (the third state). I know sometimes you're not sure if you have a pain somewhere so a "I don't know" or "I'm not sure" could be interesting (or not).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLna7h.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: These appear to be links.  If there were a lot of them on the page, there would be no clear way to show which ones were selected.  Styling them as buttons (each with an active and inactive state) with "I don't know" selected by default for each would be more effective.

Comment: @3nafish I agree with you, there are probably better ways to design the choices and dozens of links on a page are clearly not a great thing. However, a selected link could be bold, not underlined, an other color, ...

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can easily replicate the "real-world" habit on a web page unless you want to let your users really draw something (a cross, a circle). Instead you could use a 3-state UI element, e.g. a checkbox to represent that. The user can cycle through the possible values (undetermined, no pain, pain). A state label beside that can show what the current check state means.

A nicer way would be to use a horizontal slider button with 3 positions, left for `undetermined`, middle for `no pain` and right position for `pain`. By aligning those controls you can then show a header line that displays the meaning of the 3 positions, instead to replicate it over and over again for each individual entry.

Yet another possibility is to use the very common star rating approach (maybe even with more than 3 possible values to let the user choose how strong the pain is, where appropriate).

Comment: Your mockups don't actually show what your proposal would look like. The sliders don't allow 3 states, and the check boxes don't show the state clearly and need that label you're talking about. You can use the embedded Balsamic tool to make the sketches to illustrate your point. As to using the three-state checkbox at all: I would *not* do this. The grey state has a specific meaning of 'mixed' (usually: some children checked, some unchecked). What would that translate to in this context?

Comment: Sorry, yes, these are just images I grabbed from somewhere, no real mockups. Just to support the ideas.

Comment: The problem is that they show something _different_ than the idea, and thus confuse more than they clarify. Please edit your answer so they images show the actual solution you want to suggest instead.