# Asking a Yes/No/(N/A) Question

Tags: mobile, input, surveys

I seek a better solution for taking input for a three-state yes, no, or does not apply question for a survey I'm creating. My current solution looks like the following:
[image]

One requirement is that the solution needs to be responsive for devices. Here's how it resizes in mobile (no suprises here):

[image]

Any ideas would be *much* appreciated!

EDIT: The solution I have above is a bit too static, and I'm hoping for something a bit more interactive for the user. Any ideas?

Comment: What end effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: You could take a look at [Bootstrap radio buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons)

Comment: You say you want something better than your current version, but you've not really said what it is that is wrong with this one. Why doesn't this design work for you? What are the problems with it? How do you know it's wrong?

Comment: In [this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50747/three-state-button-for-a-medical-chart) there are some examples given for the same problem. See the first image in the accepted answer which uses a slider that might give you the feeling of a less static ui.

Comment: The issue I'm having with the current solution I have is that it simply doesn't feel as interactive as I'd like it to. It feels a bit too static for me. Any ideas?

Comment: The phrase "doesn't feel as interactive as I'd like to" seems a little strange to me - almost like you're trying to force unnecessary interactions on a user. It's just a yes/no question it doesn't need anything spectacular.

Comment: The separators between the three choices that emphasis that they are each a separate clickable object seem to be missing to me.

Comment: @AnindyaBasu, you have a fair point. Especially with as many instances on the page there will be at one time, I probably should keep it simple. I'm new to the community, but I've found all of your comments helpful. Cheers.

Comment: @jonzfisher welcome to the community!

Comment: You could take some button ideas from Codrops and implement them... There are really nice effects that you could use, some of them play with 3D like your buttons. Check the red section: http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have a UX issue here as you already solved that. It's more of a UI problem with the flatness of your design. There is no affordance here. Am I supposed to tap or click on N/A... You see what I mean? Make them look like you should touch them.

If its a survey I would also consider to definitely NOT pre-select anything as you showed in your example. You don't want to a) persuade or b) choose by proxy.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

how about having a check mark and a cross next to the yes and no to make it more visually understandable.

is there's a certain reason to use yes,no,n/a in that particular order? is it a best practice? there might be a tendency to get more 'yes' responses.